# ZKTeco (Bio-metric Fingerprint + Card): Save data to my local Database

Tags: mysql, networking, fingerprint, biometrics

I have an attendance machine [ZKTeco f18](http://www.zkteco.com/product/F18_248.html). Which can read both `Fingerprin`t and `Card`. I have access to the database of it. I want to keep data from this machine database to my local PC dababase like `MySQL`. What will be the steps of this work.

**Which language will be preferable for this work?

Comment: can you share how  could you access to the database of F18?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it has TCP/IP support assign an IP address to it on the same subnet as your PC so that you can reach it via network (assuming it is connected to your LAN), you could use Php scripting language to access the database and save it to your PC's MySQL. Atleast for me that's what I would use. Which data would from the device would you want to archive in your PC? The fingerprint data or the reports?